# excel comparison of two datasets

Tags: excel, datetime, comparison

I am having a little difficulty conceptually understanding how to complete a task. Please forgive the context, but it will help.

I have a set of timetable information that contains the following

```
Date_Start (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)
Date_End (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)
Activity_location (String, code, example: B/B/012)
Other information that is not important
```

We have performed an audit (people going and doing a manual check on room occupancy). This audit was done using a google form which has now produced a spreadsheet. Unfortunately this doesn't quite match the format of the other one and instead contains:

```
Date
Time
B/B/012
B/B/011
... etc.
```

The problem is that each room is an individual column, regardless of if it was audited, which produces .... a lot of columns. I have already combined the Date and Time from the second dataset to produce a comparable datetime.

My task it to compare the information, so I have the timetable data (what should have happened) and I have the audit information (what did happen) and I need to find any discrepancies.

I am just having a little difficulty understanding how I might get these datasets into a format where I can compare them. I would really appreciate any help you might be able to give.

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft Excel or Google's Spreadsheets? They are not the same.

Comment: Actually either, although I do prefer Excel - everything is where I expect it.

Comment: I'll write an answer (too long for a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Excel and you do have the dates (stripped from unneeded characters) in a column, you simply need to tell Excel how to interpret these values as dates. For instance, if you have the value `1/3/16`, Excel may interpret it as March 1st, 2016 or Jan 3td, 2016.

To tell Excel how to interpret dates, you select the column (all cells in the column having values), right-click and select **Format cells...**. There, you can tell Excel that the value should be read as `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`.

Once you have Excel fully aware of the meaning of those dates, you can simply compare them (e.g. `if(B3>G3...` will check if the date in B3 is *later* than that in G3).

Hope this assists you to proceed.

**UPDATE**

Based on the exchange through comments, here is my final answer.

If you need to establish a relation (say between spreadsheet "A" and spreadsheet "B") when not only there is a on-to-one relation between columns/rows of both sheets, and (even worse) the one-to-many correlation is not predictable (meaning, in one case you have a one-to-one, in the next a one-to-4 and in the next a one-to-17), the only solution is either pivoting one of the tables or writing some MACROS.

I don't see any other way our of this. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not having any difficulty in comparison of dates. I concatenated the separate date and time into a datetime that is easily comparable.

The issue I am having, I guess, is that the datasets are in a different format (one has one row per entry per room, the other has a row that contains entries for many rooms, and multiple rows per date-time).

Comment: I see... You may try to PIVOT your second table to generate something resembling your first table.

Comment: Yeah, I did try this but it wasn't really in a format that I could then do a comparison with. I fear the answer is actually going to be a VBA macro that takes the multiple entries on a single row and split them into many rows. I really don't want to have to do that though :(

Comment: I updated my answer so you can (kindly) mark it, even though it is not the answer you wished to get.